# Same function needs to be called simultaneously for all users in php

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

I have a `start_processing("set 1")` function which takes 6 hrs to complete set1,

I want to process set 2, set 3 .... how can i process all of them in same time ?? since when i put

```
<?php
start_processing("set1");
start_processing("set2");
start_processing("set3");
?>
```

It takes 18 hrs.

I want to complete process in 6hrs for all processing.

**Finally i got a solution**

I have take **[curl_multi](http://php.net/curl_multi_init)** - it is far better. Save the handshakes - they are not needed every time!

Use **[curl_multi_init](http://php.net/curl_multi_init)** to run the processes in parallel. This can have a tremendous effect.

Comment: you can use the cron job and run all method at one time

Comment: Set separate cron's for each `start_processing()`, you can complete in 6 hours.

Comment: I have use one cron file execute every minute. millions of users in our site. so separate cron is not possible. if i set cron separate file means i need to set millions of crons. So only i create singe cron file for every minute.

Comment: but will your cron complete in 1 minute??

Comment: No it will take some time.

Comment: If it takes 18 hours to complete, why execute it every minute ?? You should expand the question to include more information ...

Comment: @Joe Watkins now i provide some example to understand more.

Comment: @Joe Watkins so i have created one cron function and that function execute once user register. so now 3 users registered same time so i want run that function each user at same time with out any delay. if i use loop means first function completed then only start the second set of function. so it will take more time

Comment: Running something that takes 6 hours to execute "without delay" is a contradiction in terms - it doesn't make any sense ...  update the question with a clear description of the whole problem and your current solution.

Comment: @NathanSrivi are we sure this isn't an XY problem?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using PHP as Apache-module, you can use [pcntl_fork](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) to create several processes of which each processes one function call.

```
if(pcntl_fork())
    start_processing("set1");
else if(pcntl_fork())
    start_processing("set2");
else
    start_processing("set3");
```

If you have a varying number of working sets, just put them in an array and loop through it. Just bear in mind that too many processes could overload your system!

Another, more lightweight, option is the use of [php pthreads](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php) which AFAIK work with Apache, but require installing the corresponding php-extension first.

A third possibility is, as mentioned by sandeep_kosta and Niranjan N Raju, to create one Cronjob for each working set.